# Semicolon in conditional structures

Tags: bash, scripting

Why put semicolons in one and not in another?

The result is the same

**Code one**

```
if [ "a" == "a" ]
then
 echo "true"
fi
```

**Code two**

```
if [ "a" == "a" ];
then
 echo "true";
fi
```

Semicolons in the second code are unnecessary?

When it is necessary to place semicolons?

Comment: This has been sufficiently and properly answered, but I wanted to let the OP also know that ; just replaces *any* end-of-line, so you can combine two commands into one line, e.g.: `svn up; make`

Comment: Note also that two semi-colons `;;` are used to separate matches in case statements.  `;;` is required here, not optional....but `;;` isn't the same thing as `;` or `; ;`, it just looks a bit like it.  Single semi-colons `;` work as normal in the COMMANDS parts of a case statements.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The semicolon is needed only when the end of line is missing:

```
if [ "a" == "a" ] ; then echo "true" ; fi
```

Without semicolons, you get Syntax error.

I do not understand your question about quotes. Can you be more specific?

(And by the way, using `=` instead of `==` is more portable and POSIX compliant).

Comment: Quotes in the second code are unnecessary?

Comment: All the quotes in both the samples are unnecessay.

Answer (score 9):

The semicolon is often used, because some folks (/me e.g.) like a style like this:

```
if [ ... ]; then
   doit-it-then
else
   doit-it-else
fi
```

So, if the then-keyword is placed on the condition-line then it is neccessary because a new command starts, as written by choroba.

Concerning the quotes in the condition-check they are often used with variables to make sure no exception occurs if nothing is assigned to the variable. This is a safer style and looks unneccessary, but even in shell-programming it has from time to time made programs process though contents couldn't be assigned to variables. Then the command is still working because an empty string is compared.