# Are `if` and `then` actually programs

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I've read that semicolon is used to separate programs:

```
$ echo 3; ls -la
```

Does it mean that `if`, `then` and `else` are separate programs here?

```
$ if [ $VARIABLE == abcdef ] ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi
```

This question is not about semicolons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semicolon in conditional structures](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48805/semicolon-in-conditional-structures)

Comment: @StephenRauch Not really a duplicate. More it's a reasonable outgrowth from that Q, as an attempt at further understanding.

Comment: More programm-y formulation: `[ $variable == abcdef ] && echo yes || echo no`

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that's not strictly equivalent,  if the statement within the first branch fails, the second will also execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Comment: run `type if`, `type else` on your terminal and you'll know. When in doubt for any command, just use `type`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `;` separates statements (loosely speaking). It is (almost) always possible to replace a `;` by a newline.

To say that `;` separates two programs, therefore `if` and `then` must be "programs" is a bit too simplistic as a statement may be made of reserved words, shell functions, built-in utilities and external utilities, and combinations of these using pipes and boolean operators etc. etc.

Both `if` and `then` are reserved words in the [shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10), not "programs". Here they are used to build up what's technically called a *compound command*.

`echo` is likely a built-in utility in the shell (but doesn't need to be), and `ls` is probably an external utility (or "program" as you say).

Answer (score 7):

Whilst that is a fair first approximation when one is starting out learning the very basics of using shells, at the level of "here is how one runs a program" and "here is how one runs multiple programs one after another on a single line", it is not actually true.

The harder to grasp for a beginner but more correct explanation is that the shell language is a **computer language**.  It has a **syntax**.  That syntax comprises various **lexical elements** including (amongst other things) newlines, operators, words, and reserved words.

`if`, `then`, `else`, and `fi` are all **reserved words**.  They have particular meanings when **parsing** the input that one gives to a shell, according to its **grammar**.  Similarly, `;` is a separator **operator**.

Input in the shell language is thus, taken as a whole, a computer program that is **interpreted** by another program, an **interpreter**, the shell.  Its individual grammatical parts are not programs.  The shell language is a way of specifying (other) programs for the shell to run.

`[` is not a special lexical element in the shell grammar such as an operator.  It is an ordinary **word**, that names one such program named `[`.  Many shells have a **built-in** version of this program, combined into the code of the shell program itself, but you can also find an **external** program by this name somewhere such as `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[`, which programs *other than* shells can invoke.  Equally, `]` isn't a special shell lexical element either.  It's an ordinary word, that becomes an argument for the `[` program.  The `[` program requires that its final argument, when it is executed, be `]`, which it proceeds to then ignore.

Another similar program named in your question is `echo`.  Again, most shells have a built-in version of this program.  But again there is also an external version of the program, somewhere such as `/bin/echo` or`/usr/bin/echo`, for programs *other than* shells to invoke.

A third program named in your question is `ls`.  Shells generally do not have built-in versions of this program, and it is an external program, to be found somewhere such as `/bin/ls` or `/usr/bin/ls`.

For the Bourne Again shell, you can read more about this in the *Basic Shell Features* of the GNU Bourne Again shell info documentation.  Other shells have different grammars, naturally.  The *Single Unix Specification* describes a syntax that all POSIX-conformant shells (in their POSIX-conformant modes) are supposed to adhere to.

## Further reading

- "[Shell Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10)".  *Shell Command Language*.  Base Specifications Issue 7.  The Open Group.  IEEE 1003.1-2008.  ISBN 1937218812.
- [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).  *Utilities*.  Base Specifications Issue 7.  The Open Group.  IEEE 1003.1-2008.  ISBN 1937218812.
- "[Shell Grammar](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html)".  *The Z Shell Manual*.  version 5.3.1.  2017.

Answer (score 5):

It is actually not far-fetched to think of `if`, `then` and `else` as external programs. In fact, the Thompson shell in the original 1st edition Unix implemented `if` and `goto` as external programs. This is possible because the subprocess shares file descriptors with the shell process, so a (forward) goto just had to read input until it finds the target label and then exits. See [Thompson shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_shell).

Comment: Or indeed see Laurent Bercot's [`if`](http://www.skarnet.org/software/execline/if.html) and [`ifelse`](http://www.skarnet.org/software/execline/ifelse.html), which are parts of `execline`.  These are not the `if` in the question, though.

Comment: _"It is actually not far-fetched to think of if, then and else as external programs"_ Well, it is, because they're not.

Answer (score 2):

The `then` and `else` are not programs. The other parts are. Notice there's no `;`' directly after them, but after the command they precede.

The `[ ... ]` *is* a command, and needs the `;` if followed by the beginning of another command.

AFAIK, all of control structures in Bash, and *probably* most *nix shells, are the same. They are instructions to the interpreter. The test or condition, on the other hand, uses a program/process that is "executed" and are commands. Since `then` is part of the line that leads to the `echo` command it has to be separated by a newline from the previous command `[ ... ]`. It doesn't need to be separated from the command it controls, the `echo yes`.

Legally, although ugly and hard to read, you could also do this.

```
if [ $VARIABLE == abcdef ]
then echo yes
else echo no
fi
```

Notice that there's no need for `;` between the controls at all here, even though they are not on their own line.

Interestingly enough, the whole control structure (`if ... fi`) is a shell command, and the entirety has to end with a newline or a `;`. The last line can't be `fi echo done` but must be `fi; echo done`. The same as an assignment `VARIABLE='abcdef'` is a command.

Even though the whole control structures are commands, they still are not programs.

Answer (score 1):

`if`, `elif`, `then`, and `fi` are all reserved keywords used to implement one of the constructs referred to as a compound command in shell, which means there cannot be a command (or rather, another command) by any of those names in shell. The purpose of the `;` in general is not to separate commands, but to terminate a command *list*. For example, the following is a valid `if` statement:

```
if echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; then echo done; echo really done; fi
```

The condition of the `if` statement is the command list `echo foo; echo bar; echo baz`. The parser knows that the condition is over because `then`, which immediately follows a semi-colon, cannot be a command because it is a reserved keyword. Thus, it knows that what *follows* `then` is the start of the body. Likewise, `fi` is a reserved keyword and thus cannot be a third command in the body of the `if` statement, but marks the end of the compound command.

Comment: thanks, if this is used `if program1 foo; program2 bar; program3  baz; `, which program status should be `0`, so that shell proceeds to `then`? The last one?

Comment: Just `program3 baz`. The exit status of a list of commands is the exit status of the last command in that list. The other two can fail without affecting the condition.